# How to wait for bulk of rest API calls to finish?

Tags: reactjs

I need to build a data table that in addition to the normal fields, each row has it's own rules.
For iluustration:
[image]

I don't have all the data in hand when building the row, so while building each one I need to call getRule() for each of its rules.

What I did is:

```
this.data.forEach( (row) => {

            this.sortedRules = row.Rules.sort(function(a, b){
                a = a.Name.toLowerCase()
                b = b.Name.toLowerCase()
                if(a < b) { return -1; }
                if(a > b) { return 1; }
                return 0;
            })

            this.sortedRules.map ( rule => {
                ruleSpecEditor.isRuleEnabled(rule.Id, this.userSessionId).then( (enabled) => {
                    this.setState({
                        [rule.Name+"_Enabled"]: enabled
                    })
                })

                // Promise.all(ruleEditor.getRule(rule.Id, this.userSessionId)).then( (ruleStruct) => {
                ruleEditor.getRule(rule.Id, this.userSessionId).then( (ruleStruct) => {

                    this.setState({
                        [rule.Name+"_Valid"]: ruleStruct.Valid,
                        [rule.Name+"_ErrorDescription"]: ruleStruct.ErrorDescription
                    }, () => {
                        this.buildSingleRule(row)
                    })

                }) //getRule call
            }) //sorted rules map

            this.buildRow(row)

            // console.log("Json: ", jsonData)
            rows.push(this.jsonData);
        }) //foreach rows loop

      this.setState({rows: rows})
```

The problem that in such case I'm getting the rows but without the rules because of the async call.
How can I deal with it?

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: If I correctly understood how it works, it can deal with different api calls, but not with the same call several times (bulk)

Comment: At the end I customized the API to retrieve all data instead of dealing it from client side